# Prove $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\:\frac{x}{n(1+nx^2)}$ converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus

Prove that the series

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\:\frac{x}{n(1+nx^2)}$

converges uniformly on R

i know that for every $\epsilon>0$ there is some $N$ such that for $x$, if $n$ >$N$ then |$f(x)$-$f_n(x)$|

but i dont really know how to prove this all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let

$$f_n(x)=\frac{x}{n(1+nx^2)}$$

Notice that $f_n$ is odd so it suffices to answer the question by working on $\Bbb R_+$.

We have
$$f'_n(x)=\frac{n-n^2x^2}{n^2(1+nx^2)^2}=0\iff x=\frac1{\sqrt n}$$
and the series
$$\sum_{n\ge1}||f_n||_\infty=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac1{2n\sqrt n}$$
is convergent so by the M-test the given series is uniformly convergent on $\Bbb R$.